# How to get relationship between noun phrases in a sentence?

Tags: java, nlp

I have this pattern to get cause-effect relationship between noun phrases in a sentence:

```
<NP I> * have * effect/impact on/in <NP II>
```

NP is Noun Phrase.

If I have a sentence:

```
Technology can have negative impact on social interactions
```

then based on above pattern, **NP I** match with **Technology** and **NP II** match with **social interactions**

The question: what is appropriate algorithm to get NP I and NP II?

Thanks

Comment: You may wish to make your question more specific, as an algorithm for identifies general noun phrases in sentences would be fairly complex and require hours of work to compile a list of key words to identify in sentences.

Comment: I just realized I may have misunderstood your question; posting an answer now.

Comment: @Vulcan I'm sorry, I have added a example for better explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.  I have posted an answer.  EDIT: I just realized what the * meant; I'll modify my answer momentarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression (RegEx) is extremely useful in cases like this.  The following regex matches your string format and allows for you to analyze the differing variables of the input.

```
([\\w\\s]*?) (\\w*?) have (\\w*?) (effect|impact) (on|in) ([\\w\\s]*?)(\\.)
```

By running the following program, you can see how regex matcher groups work, and that group 1 is NP 1, and group 6 is NP 2.

```
public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s]*?) (\\w*?) have (\\w*?) (effect|impact) (on|in) ([\\w\\s]*?)(\\.)");
        String s = "Greenhouse gases can have negative impact on global warming.";
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        if (m.find()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + m.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, the string `"Greenhouse gases can have negative impact on global warming."` is analyzed.  The following is the output of the program.

```
Group 0: Greenhouse gases can have negative impact on global warming.
Group 1: Greenhouse gases
Group 2: can
Group 3: negative
Group 4: impact
Group 5: on
Group 6: global warming
```